# Problem with sqlAlchemy model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I have the following situation. I have a class DataTypes which has the following structure:

```
class DataType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DATA_TYPES'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type_name = Column(String)
    fk_result_storage = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('DATA_STORAGES.id'))

    parentDataStorage = relationship("DataStorage", backref=backref("DataType",    cascade="all,delete"))

    def __init__(self, name, resultId):
       self.type_name = name
       self.fk_result_storage = resultId
```

Now the relationship defined here works. But now I have some specific data types that are created dynamically trough introspection and that need to be deleted cascaded also. They are created like this:

```
t = Table('DATA_' + obj.__name__.lower(), *t[:-1], **t[-1])
mapper(obj, t, *args, **kwargs)
model.Base.metadata.create_all(dao.Engine)
```

This works fine and tables are created as needed. But now I want to add a relationship 
similar to the one from DataType class. So I tried this:

```
t = T('DATA_' + obj.__name__.lower(), *t[:-1], **t[-1])
M(obj,t,properties = {'children' : relationship('DataType', backref=backref(obj, cascade="all,delete"))} )   
model.Base.metadata.create_all(dao.Engine)
```

But this gives me:

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: relationship 'children' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <type 'str'>)
```

I`m quite new to SQLAlchemy. Any suggestions ?

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: Do you need to be using `obj.__name__.lower()` instead of `obj` when declaring the Children relationship? Something about that part seems off to be, but I admit I have limited experience with sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is not my strongest skill, but I think this property is wrong:

```
properties = {'children' : relationship('DataType', backref=backref(obj, cascade="all,delete"))}
```

I think this should be:

```
properties = {'children' : relationship(DataType, backref=backref(obj, cascade="all,delete"))}
```

I.E., the reference to the DataType is the class, not a string.

Comment: I was about to say this was probably not the problem, but I think you may be right: the declarative extension does allow you to refer to as-yet-undefined classes with strings, but only within the class declaration I think.

Comment: Yes, thanks that was the main problem. Also I needed to pass str(obj) to backref.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as long as you are using the declarative extension, using a string reference for the datatype is easiest since the sequence of declarations doesn't matter. You only have to make sure that you use the same 1 instance of Base `declarative_base()`.

See [this post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.sqlalchemy.user/29862)